# NSDateFormatter always return nil when i formated week or month,why？

Tags: objective-c, swift

Test  as follow

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        fmt.dateFormat = @"EEE";
        NSDate *createDate = [fmt dateFromString:@"Fri"];
        NSLog(@"%@",createDate);
        fmt.dateFormat = @"MMM";
        createDate = [fmt dateFromString:@"May"];
        NSLog(@"%@",createDate);
        fmt.dateFormat = @"dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy";
        createDate = [fmt dateFromString:@"08 11:51:54 +0800 2016"];
        NSLog(@"%@",createDate);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

but with **Swift** language ,there is no problem.

```
var str = "Wed Jun 08 11:51:54 +0800 2016"

var fmt = NSDateFormatter()
    fmt.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"

var date = fmt.dateFromString(str);

var str2 = fmt.stringFromDate(date!);
```

[image]

```
var str = "Wed Jun"

var fmt = NSDateFormatter()
    fmt.dateFormat = "EEE MMM"

var date = fmt.dateFromString(str);

var str2 = fmt.stringFromDate(date!);
```

[image]
I want to know why and how to deal with this problem in **Objective-C**.Thanks very much!

Comment: Unsure but it looks like you are trying to create a date and the only information you are providing is either a days name or a months name. I don't believe that would be enough information for a date formatter to create a date. Also your swift example doesn't attempt to do what is happening in the obj-c example

Comment: Could you please post your code in code blocks instead of screenshots? Would be easier for others to copy and test out :)

Comment: Thanks for your attention.I have posted my code

Comment: See my answer  and do like that@eveloson... i hope it help you..

Answer (score 0):

Getting date from string:

```
NSString *dateString = @"10-06-2016";
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = [fmt dateFromString:dateString];
```

converting into our required date format:

```
[fmt setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"];
NSString *reqDateString = [fmt stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"date is %@", reqDateString);
```

Comment: Yes,it is ok. But I want format the string like  "Wed Jun 08 11:51:54 +0800 2016"

Comment: Now above code print like: date is Friday, June 10, 2016 ....just make some changes to add 11:51:54 +0800 in that( which you got this already )...@eveloson